# $A$ is a square matrix and $\ker A^{n-1} \neq \ker A^n$ where $n≥2$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I struggle with answering the question in preparation for the linear math exam. In class we haven't touched F and worked mainly on R.

$A$ is a square matrix and $\ker A^{n-1} \neq \ker A^n$ where $n≥2$
1) Does $A$ have infinitely many invariant sub-spaces?

2) Is $\ker A^{m-1} \neq \ker A^m$ for all $1 < m≤n$?